# Edittext inside radiogroup

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button

I'm trying to get layout as below:

```
|--r1--|---EditText---|

|--r2--|---TextView---|
```

the widgets at "r1" and "r2" position is `RadioButton`,

I wish:
r1 and r2 should be in same `RadioGroup`.
I am not able to place `EditText` next to r1.
textview next to r2 is easy.

Can some one help?

Comment: what layout are you using? better go for relative layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LinearLayout 1 - Horizontal

    linear layout 2 - Vertcal
         RadioGroup with you radio buttons
    close linear layout 2

    linear layout 3 - Vertical
         edit Text here
    close linear layout 3


close LinearLayout 1
```

Hope this structure could help.

The code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here it is  :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sample text" />

</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sample text" />

</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i want add in same radiogroup :(

Comment: I can see two differnt radiogroups :(

Comment: Ty, just what I needed. In the accepted answer edittexts may not align with radiobuttons perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It will be look like this
[image]

Comment: the problem in the code is i can check both radiobutton..:( i want when i select a single radiobutton other should be unchecked automatically.. although using radiogroup bt same error occurs

Answer (score 1):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_8">

       <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_ends_after"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_until_cancelled_never"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/txt_until_cancelled_never" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_after_occurrence"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/txt_after"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_occurrence"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rg_ends_after"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_after_occurrence_dummy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="@string/txt_after" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_occurrence"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="2"
                android:ems="2"
                android:text="@string/number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_occurrence"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/txt_occurrence" />

        </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**GridLayout**" to achieve. I have done in my programm.

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <RadioGroup>
      <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </RadioGroup>
   <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this code
radioButton is a variable for any RadioButton you want to attach EditText

```
radioButton.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout()
   {
      radioButton.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)editText.getLayoutParams();
      params.leftMargin = radioButton.getLeft() + radioButton.getWidth() + littleSpacing;
      params.topMargin = radioButton.getTop() + radioButton.getBaseline() - editText.getBaseline();
   }
});
```